# Skipping lines in Grep

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I'm searching a file for a repeated string using grep on windows. I've got it working more or less.

I'm updating a large batch file with some IP addresses. When I add a new location into the file sometimes the T1 IP address isn't available so that location gets a T1 IP of null. So periodically I go back through the list to update them.

I search for lines with SET T1=null. That returns those specific lines so I added the -BX to go back X lines where the site number is. This gives me a block of text which includes both the site number and IP of null. Hooray progress.

However I would like to filter it down further and preferably just get the site numbers.

So instead of getting this:

```
:S001
Text I want to skip here
More text here
SET T1=null
--
:S010
```

I could get this:

```
:S001
--
:S010
```

To summarize, I would like to find a match, then go back up X lines, output that line to a file and nothing else, move onto the next match, repeat.

I suspect I could achieve this with gawk, but alas my awk fu has long since left me so I'm at a loss.

Comment: grep for site numbers.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I do want just the site numbers, however I only want the site numbers that also have a missing T1 IP.

Comment: so what? you've already solved that task. process the results further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your extension requirements are heading in the direction of `sed` or `awk` (or Perl, Python, …, though `awk` is fine here); `grep` is no longer appropriate.

```
awk '/^:S.*/ { site = $1; next } /SET T1=null/ { print site }'
```

Capture the lines starting `:S` (make that more rigorous as you need — for example, maybe `/^:S[0-9]{3}$/` looks for a line containing `:S` and 3 digits only), keeping the name in the variable `site`.  When you encounter a `SET T1=null` line, print the current value of `site` — the most recently encountered site name.  You can add bells and whistles as needed to make it more robust if your input data is flakier than this expects.  You could omit the `next` in this example; it is a minor optimization.

Answer (score 0):

@Jonathan Leffler
OK thank you Jonathan for getting me on the right path.

I was able to get exactly what I was looking for with a wee bit of tweaking. Mostly due to me being on Windows using the GNUwin32 packages as opposed to on linux/unix.

```
C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin>gawk "/^:S.*/ { site = $1; next } /SET T1=null/ { print site }" c:\file.txt >c:\match.txt
```

Comment: I fully endorse and recommend [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/) for small Bash tasks under Windows: no pesky Windows shell weirdness, not as heavyweight as Cygwin...